# How can I sort the contents by vote up?

Tags: 7, views, rating

I am using a `Thumbs Up/Down` widget of [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module. Rate module uses the [Voting API](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi) module to store the vote value. I want to use both `Up/Down` for vote.

I want to add a sorting filter so It can sort by `Up` value only. I can write the custom views handler but voting api stores the value like :

```
entity_id [123], value (1), tag (my_tag)
entity_id [134], value (1), tag (my_tag)
entity_id [123], value (-1), tag (my_tag)
entity_id [123], value (1), tag (my_tag)
entity_id [134], value (1), tag (my_tag)
```

I want to add a query : `Sum of Rows which has value 1 per entity_id`.

How can I do this?

Comment: @Clive No answer on that post.

Comment: Doesn't mean the question needs to be duplicated - if we were talking about a question from a year ago then fair enough, but this one was asked last week. The bounty system exists for exactly this reason